# Tableau read and update data source ( From Web data connector) automatically

Tags: tableau-api

I am installed and added data source (web data connector) inside tableau

```
Web data connector URL : http://localhost/datasouceexample/example.html
```

we data connector holds some data. 
import data from web data connector and created graphs using the data's  from the web data connector URL .Generated graph and saved in "tableau public" option.
Embed the code inside my web application . Graphs shows perfectly.

My question is about the automatic data updation .

1 ) I want to update graph automatically  based on the value from web data connector URL 
2 ) If any new updations are inside input datas (new inputs) , automatically sync with tableau and update the graph,so no changes in the embed code and graph updated automatically

Any settings available inside tableau for do this section? if it is possible ? Thanks

Comment: You can set a refresh schedule on Tableau Server, but I don't know of this capability on Tableau Desktop

Comment: Is this service available in paid version ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by paid version. It's for Tableau Server, which is costly. It is an additional cost in addition to a paid version of Tableau Desktop.

Answer (score 3):

Only dashboards with a google sheets datasource can be automatically updated on Tableau Public.  Maybe you could redesign your web service to write to a google sheets doc.  If so, you could republish your dashboard to sync with that doc.

Comment: Could you confirm this? Because I have a file too large to be hosted on Google Sheet. I built a Web Data Connector and I connected Tableau Public to a Firebase branch. Now the problem is how to sync tableau with firebase. It seems that the only way is to update the data manually.

Comment: Hi Paolo...yes, this would be manual on Tableau Public.  If you need to host/connect to a 'large' file.  Look into purchasing a Tableau Online...it's very cost effective.

Answer (score 0):

The scenario you are describing is not possible using Tableau Public (the free version of Tableau software) and the web data connector.  Tableau Public does not support updating web data connector data once published on Public, you would need to refresh the data from your desktop application and republish.

The closest supported path to your use case would be, as Kara_F mentioned in the comments, to use Tableau Server.  With that product, you can create web data connector datasources and publish them to your Server.  You can then schedule a refresh job which will update your data at a certain interval.  More info for keeping WDC data up to date can be found here: http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/v0.0/server/en-us/datasource_wdc.htm.