# How to add mysql as data source in Tableau Public

Tags: tableau-api

I installed and created some reports in tableau using static excel and web data connector, installed tableau shows Odata, Google Sheet and Web data connector are used for data connection.

[image]

I want to draw dynamic charts based on database values. So how can I connect tableau with MySql.

I am using "Tableau Public 10.0" version

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can. I think the mysql connectors only available on the paid professional version. Data sources for the public version from the website are below:

Data Sources

- Google Sheets
- Microsoft Excel 2007 or later
- Microsoft Windows Azure Marketplace DataMarket
- OData
- Text files － comma separated value (.csv) files
- Statistical Files; SAS (*.sas7bdat), SPSS (*.sav), and R (*.rdata,
  *.rda)
- Web Data Connectors

See here for the full list:
https://public.tableau.com/en-us/s/download

Comment: Thanks lampbob for your reply , Using web data connectors can we draw dynamic graphs automatically can u check this link      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39226767/tableau-read-and-update-data-source-from-web-data-connector-automatically

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure. I know you can set a scheduler for the web data connectors on tableau server. But again I would think this is only on the paid version. I'd open a new question and someone else might be able to help?     

Looking at the original question you may be able to link your MySQL data via the web connectors but it would involve calling the data into a web page first via JavaScript I think. Then connecting the web connectors to that page.